New to Blender: Question about lighting
I'm quite new to Blender and was curious as to why on opening Blender for the first time it is presumed that the user will need a lighting object in the Scene hierarchy?
Is it possible to give meshes a set colour and have no lighting and shading effects being imposed over them by a lighting source? Is this a realistic way of making a scene for a game that is intended to be retro without fancy lighting and shadows?
Thanks.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

You have a light, a camera and a cube in the default scene. If you hit F12 to render, it just works. It's just the most simple scene that works, that's all. It's in no way an attempt to imply that you need to have those objects in your scene and most users customize the scene and its settings and save whatever default scene that suits them and their needs for when starting a new project. You can and probably should do that as well:

You need light in your scene, because rendering is calculating light. The whole idea is about simulating light interactions in your scene in most cases. It's possible to make shaders that just emit light themselves and do not necessarily receive shadows or produce any realistic shading. One way to do that could be to use emission shaders and limit their effects only to the camera(as opposed to emitting light to the scene as well) by using Light Path node:

You can make all sorts of effects that way, however, as you can see the objects become completely flat, so it might be that you might want to just have primitive lighting and some more primitive shadows. There are may tools for achieving any look that you want, even ToonBSDF shader for Cycles and Shader to RGB node for EEVEE that let's you have lots of control over how shaders behave.

You can really do whatever you want and the default scene with a cube, a light and a camera should definitely not be viewed as intended to impose anything.

Thank you for your informative response.
I think the shader emitting light itself is what I may end up relying on. I'm basically in the early stages of developing a 2.5D RPG that will be similar in appearance to RuneScape Classic (picture of Classic here: https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/OulpO0UdztMk1vCdzi4AV7ql8H8=/0x0:512x343/1820x1213/filters:focal(176x92:256x172):format(webp)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/59824465/runescape_classic.0.jpg ).
I think Classic did not have world lighting which is why I was fore mostly questioning the default lighting source that appeared.

What I should also add is I'm putting a lot of emphasis on developing a game that does not use up too much computer resources. I'm guessing that 'simulating light interactions' is quite a constant drag on resources to some extent. I'm definitely looking to define where my light and shadows will appear much the same way an Artist would do with a static painting, rather than have the engine dynamically control these things.

I would advise to do some studying first. If you have a goal of making a game, you should at least be familiar with basic concepts in CG. Learning to use Blender might be very useful, but you should also have a look at tools specifically designed to make games - game engines. Look into actual game design as a subject as well.

Yes I've spent the last 6 months learning Godot 4 and Gdscript. Unfortunately, the tutorial didn't explain that you can import Blender projects into Godot 4; I thought the graphics were entirely managed inside Godot. So I'm now learning Blender as well as Laigter from scratch given their importance.
